# How to show username already exist validation using jquery validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have searched about this but got answer just for php.I need to
validate username already exist message in asp.net mvc using juqery validation plugin.I have done validation on Name require which is working perfectly on modal popup but not able to implement on already username exist.

**Controller:**

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                bool isUserExist = WebSecurity.UserExists(registerModel.Username);
                if (isUserExist)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Username", "UserName already exist");
                }
```

**View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Validation Code**

```
 $('#register').validate({

            rules: {
                FullName: {
                    required: true,

                },
                Username: {
                    required: true,

                }
            },
            messages: {
                Name: {
                    required: 'Name is required',
                    minlength: 'Minimum Length is 5',
                    maxlength: 'Maximum Length is 50'
                },
                Username: {
                    required: 'Username Require',
                     remote: "Email already in use!"
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Try reading this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200238/asp-net-mvc-username-availability-check. You can use `RemoteAttribute` to specify user name validation on client-side.

Comment: Demo for `RemoteAttribute` > [https://dotnetfiddle.net/uv2Qch](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uv2Qch)

Comment: @mmushtaq try but not working

Comment: "Not working" is a useless problem description. Use F12 (console) to work out what it's doing and where it's failing

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid there is no error show on console as soon as I click on save button  form get hide.

Comment: OK even that is better than "not working". According to your explanation, you never see the a call to the AJAX to check (it appears in the network tab). So it mustn't be calling the Ajax for some reason.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid actually my client side validation was working on mvc default theme but not working in bootstrap modal so I decided to use jquery validaton which work perfectly but not able to show already username exist.So now I pasted this line which is working perfectly on modal for mvc client validation. $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#register").

Answer (score 0):

You can use remote attribute to validate against server returned result.

```
  $( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: {
        url: "{Url for remote validation}",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          username: function() {
            return $( "#username" ).val();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Reference : https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/